# Build a simple project using libsodium

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, qt, libsodium

I created a very simple Qt project that's using libsodium. (I can create a same project and build well with Visual Studio 2010/2013.) But Qt Creator cannot build:

> main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol sodium_init
>   referenced in function main

This is my project:

testSodium.pro:

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = testSodium
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += SODIUM_STATIC
INCLUDEPATH += F:/libsodium-1.0.2-msvc/include
LIBS += -LF:/libsodium-1.0.2-msvc/Win32/Release/v120/static/ -llibsodium
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <sodium.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (sodium_init() == -1) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

(I'm using Qt Creator 3.3.1, Qt 5.4.1 MSVC 2010 32 bit)
libsodium: https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.2-msvc.zip

Comment: Do you have libsodium.a actually built in this directory? Try to change to -llibsodium.a in pro file

Comment: I'm using MSVC. .a is for mingw or linux, right?

Comment: And what is the actual name of your dll?

Comment: I built libsodium from source or get the lib from above link but both failed. Same error.

Comment: The name is: libsodium.lib in all cases.

Comment: I tried in .pro file: LIBS += F:/libsodium-1.0.2-msvc/Win32/Release/v120/static/libsodium.lib but failed too.

Comment: And why you use Win32? Do you have 32 bit project?

Comment: Can you take a look at libsodium-1.0.2-msvc.zip? I just try to build only. 32 or 64 is not a problem. I want to build this simple project in Qt that's using libsodium on Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74912/discussion-between-aviit-and-demonplus).

Comment: @aviit I just built it without any problem, using Qt Creator 3.1.1, Qt 5.3.0 MSVC 2010 32 bit. (http://imgur.com/RBMjmvC)

Comment: @Tay2510: Can you show me the .pro file? It's strange for me

Comment: @aviit I just use your `.pro` file, and the only differences are the `TARGET` name and my libsodium library is stored in disk `C`, so basically it works on my machine.

Comment: I have installed Qt from qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64_opengl-5.4.1.exe but in Qt Creator about says that: Qt Creator 3.3.1, Qt 5.4.1 MSVC 2010 32 bit. I have both msvc2010 and 2013 on my machine. I'm trying your version 5.3.0.

Comment: @aviit Qt version doesn't matter. Instead, the compiler version is the point. Please make sure your Qt and libsodium library are built with the same version of compiler (MSVC 2010 or 2013). For example, there could be incompatibility if you use MSVC2013 to compile Qt-MSVC2013 and  libsodium-MSVC2010 (I guess it, since it works on my machine)

Comment: @Tay2510: yes, I know that but I tried with all versions msvc 10, 11, 12 (from libsodium or built by myself)

Comment: @aviit In Qt creator, which compiler did you use to build the project?

Comment: @aviit Problem solved? What's going on?

Comment: The problem was solve (the answer now deleted) was a mix in the x86 vs. x64 binaries - this has a duplicate; http://stackoverflow.com/a/24291364/3747990

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `libsodium` is a library written in pure C.

That means if you want to import it into a C++ project, you have to add an `extern "C"` identifier.

So you should include the header file like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

#include <sodium.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Is standard practice for C libraries, that will be used by other people, to do that on their own headers. It saves other programmers having to do that on their own each time they want to call a C library from a C++ program.